# Chain creaks under pressure

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear

Just adjusted my back derailleur and now the chain makes a loud creaking noise while under pressure. When on a repair stand the shifting is perfect but while biking it’s horrible and the sound & jumping makes it uncomfortable to ride.

When adjusting i did have to loosen the barrel adjuster considerably and did not come to terms with what the H screw did, so I might have turned it but after I checked on the stand that shifting was okay I didn’t bother with it. Furthermore the chain was a little bit rusty as it has stood without lube (dry and inside) for about a week, applied lube before first ride.

Comment: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment

Comment: If the rear derailleur is perfectly aligned with the sprockets but you have problems under load the only thing I can think of is a loose/worn bottom bracket, loose chainrings or loose rear wheel/cassette. Or of course very worn cassette sprockets which cause chain skip.

Comment: A couple of things:
1)  You say it's the chain.  Do you mean it's actually the chain, or coming from the region of the chain?
2)  I've diagnosed a similar problem by putting the bike on a stand and adding drag or complete immobility to the rear wheel with one hand while pedaling with the other.  However, "only happens under power" problems are challenging to diagnose, and this has only worked for me a couple of times.
3)  If you bend each chain linkage with your fingers one at a time, are any harder to bend than others?